# Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in element <one-app-launcher-menu-item>

Tags: lightning

I see the following error (generated multiple times) in Chrome's Console when I land on the Setup page.  How can I get rid of this error?

```
aura_proddebug.js:4763 Error: [LWC error]: Invalid event type "WireContextEvent" dispatched in element <one-app-launcher-menu-item>. Event name must 1) Start with a lowercase letter 2) Contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores
<one-app-launcher-menu-item>
    <one-app-launcher-menu>
    at logError (aura_proddebug.js:4760)
    at AppLauncherMenuItem.dispatchEvent (aura_proddebug.js:8662)
    at DomContextBinding.get (contextService.js:106)
    at findContextProvisions (contextService.js:296)
    at getContextProvisions (contextService.js:337)
    at Object.getContextValues (contextService.js:368)
    at getDelegates (navigationService.js:7)
    at NavigationServiceClient.generateUrl (navigationService.js:145)
    at AppLauncherMenuItem.[GenerateUrl] (navigation.js:24)
    at AppLauncherMenuItem.getUrl (appLauncherMenuItem.js:171)
```

[image]

Comment: (a) is this impacting your ability to use setup, and (b) have you tried contacting support?

Comment: a) No, and b) No.

Comment: Try to run same thing but with disable debug mode.